# Bootstrap: column pushed after another in small display

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In displays bigger than mobile I'd like to have this disposition (in this order):

column-A large 2 - 
column-B large 8 - 
column-C large 2

In mobile I'd like to have (in different rows) the shift of the first column after the second one:

column-B large 12 - 
column-A large 6 - 
column-C large 6

Someone could tell me if it is possibile and if yes how should I do? Thanks

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: show you code and explain your issuse

Comment: I have this code now and I don't know how to do with what I would like to have in mobile version

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing `mobile first`, you should define the columns in the HTML in the order you want first:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      C
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

That makes sure it will look like what you want in small devices. And then we can add more styles for large devices.

[image]

Then on bigger devices (you said bigger than mobiles), that corresponds to `col-md-*` class in bootstrap. You can add that to the columns.
Also since you want column A appear first, you can set their orders by using bootstrap class `order-md-*`. The smaller the order, the earlier position it will get.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 order-md-2">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-1">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-3">
      C
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The result:
[image]

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/61343/

Answer (score 0):

**To mobile use `col-*`:**

Learn here :https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

and use order:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/L50gsumj/3/

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2 col-6   order-2 order-md-1">a</div>
         <div class="col-md-8 col-12  order-1 order-md-2">b</div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-6   order-3 order-md-3">c</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I have to switch (only for mobile) the first column with the second one

Comment: maybe you are really close, by logic, but doesn't work :(

Comment: what do you mean does not work ?? when?? describe issuse

Comment: with or without all the code "sm" (for mobile) is the same, it shows me the same as before have written the question :(

Comment: Sorry about edit a few times I guess it last version see my edit

Comment: try use `lg` instead of `md`

Comment: check if you have this meta:`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: yeah, I have this: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: do you see fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/L50gsumj/3/  ?? tell what not good there...